# Defining a complex-valued, piecewise function

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to define a function f(x) which yields 1.0 for x = 0 and 1.0/(2j pi x) otherwise. Here is a 'test' script I'm using:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.piecewise(x,[x==0],[1.0, lambda x: 1.0/(2j*np.pi*x)])

x = np.linspace(-1,1,21)

print(x)
print(f(x))
```

If the lambda function is not complex-valued, this works as I would expect. However, with the "2j" term I get the following warning and output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:1144: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  y[condlist[k]] = item(vals, *args, **kw)
[-1.  -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.   0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1. ]
[-0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.]
```

Apparently numpy's `piecewise` automatically takes the real part. Is this not quite a limitation of `piecewise`? Is there another way to define piecewise complex-valued functions (without having to define the real and imaginary parts separately)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`piecewise`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) docstring:

```
The output is the same shape and type as x...
```

For complex output, pass in a complex array.

Continuing your example with `f` and `x` defined:

```
In [91]: y = x + 0j

In [92]: f(y)
Out[92]: 
array([-0.+0.15915494j, -0.+0.17683883j, -0.+0.19894368j, -0.+0.2273642j ,
       -0.+0.26525824j, -0.+0.31830989j, -0.+0.39788736j, -0.+0.53051648j,
       -0.+0.79577472j, -0.+1.59154943j,  1.+0.j        ,  0.-1.59154943j,
        0.-0.79577472j,  0.-0.53051648j,  0.-0.39788736j,  0.-0.31830989j,
        0.-0.26525824j,  0.-0.2273642j ,  0.-0.19894368j,  0.-0.17683883j,
        0.-0.15915494j])
```

Comment: That works, thanks! (I finally included `x = x + 0j` as the first line of the function definition).